# Kotlin multi-criteria sort not compiling

Tags: sorting, collections, kotlin

This simple scenario

```
data class Person(var name:String, var age:Int)

var people = listOf(
        Person("Adam", 36),
        Person("Boris", 18),
        Person("Claire", 36),
        Person("Adam", 20),
        Person("Jack", 20)
)

println(people.sortedBy{compareBy{Person::age, Person::name}})
```

does not compile with

> Error:(27, 29) Kotlin: Type inference failed: Not enough information to infer parameter T in inline> fun  compareBy(crossinline selector: (T) -> Comparable<*>?): Comparator Please specify it explicitly.

Changing it to

```
println(people.sortedBy{compareBy<Person>{Person::age, Person::name}})
```

doesn't work, neither does

```
println(people.sortedBy{compareBy<Person>{Person::age}.thenBy { Person::name }})
```

giving

> Error:(28, 20) Kotlin: Type parameter bound for R in inline fun > Iterable.sortedBy(crossinline selector: (T) -> R?): List is not satisfied: inferred type Comparator is not a subtype of Comparable>

So then I also tried the multi-function overload

```
println(people.sortedBy{compareBy<Person>({it.age}, {it.name})})
```

and this yielded

> Error:(28, 20) Kotlin: Type parameter bound for R in inline fun > Iterable.sortedBy(crossinline selector: (T) -> R?): List
>    is not satisfied: inferred type Comparator is not a subtype of Comparable>

And, even more fun if I add the type parameter for `sortedBy` too

```
println(people.sortedBy<Person>{compareBy<Person>({it.age}, {it.name})})
```

This yields exactly the same problem, i.e.,

> Error:(28, 20) Kotlin: Type parameter bound for R in inline fun > Iterable.sortedBy(crossinline selector: (T) -> R?): List
>    is not satisfied: inferred type Comparator is not a subtype of Comparable>

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Fooled by distinction between `sortedWith` and `sortedBy`. Turns out that `sortedBy` uses a *single* criteria (e.g., `sortedBy(Person::name)`) whereas if you want multiple criteria, you need `sortedWith`:

```
people.sortedWith(compareBy(Person::age, Person::name))
// or
people.sortedWith(compareBy({ it.age }, { it.name }))
```

Comment: It seems you have solved your question. But your answer is quite low quality, you should add some more details!